# How to use an initialized php variable in some php block of code to an other block of php code?

Tags: php, html, mongodb, global-variables, php-mongodb

I am trying to initialize a variable called $btn with a value, and later on use that $btn value in some other php block of code.
My code is the following (explaining right after what i want to achieve) :

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
    $m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");
    $db = $m->users;
    $collection = $db->usersInfo;
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        header('Location: ../../home/website.php');
        exit;
    }
    $btn = '';
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        if(isset($_POST[$btn])){
            echo $btn;
            echo "</script>alert($btn)</script>";
            $query = $db->usersInfo;
            $filter = array('_id'=>$_SESSION['user']);
            $update = array('$addToSet'=>array('ctfs'=>$btn));
            $query->updateOne($filter,$update);
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Cyberdemia</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <!-- font awesome -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dbed6b6114.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>



        
        <div class="toggle"></div>

        <div class = "products">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <!--Will edit these in the future to get styles such as on-hover etc.-->
                    <li><a href="../ctfs.php"><small>Back</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="../../home/website.php"><small>Home</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="../../userProfile/userProfile.php"><small>Profile</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="../../signOut/signout.php"><small>Sign out</small></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class = "container">
                <h1 class = "lg-title">Welcome to the Reverse Engineering challenges</h1>
                
                <div class = "product-items">
                
                    <?php
                        $db = $m->users;
                        $collection = $db->usersInfo;
                        
                        $collectionAdmin = $db->adminInfo;
                        $query = $db->adminInfo->findOne(array('email'=>'adminMail@protonmail.com'));
                        if($query["timesLogged"] == "0"){
                            $db = $m->ctfs;
                            $collectionCtfs = $db->ctfsReverse->find();
                            foreach ($collectionCtfs as $chall){
                                $btn = $chall["challName"];
                                #echo $btn;
                                echo '<div class = "product">
                    <div class = "product-content">
                        <div class = "product-img">
                            <img src = "images/rev.png" alt = "product image">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "product-btns">
                            <form action="rev.php" method="post">
                                <button type="submit" name="'.$btn.'" value="'.$btn.'" class = "btn-cart"> play later list
                                    <span><i class = "fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                            <button type = "button" class = "btn-buy"> Play now
                                <span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-controller" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M11.5 6.027a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1 .5.5 0 0 0 0 1zm2.5-.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1 .5.5 0 0 0 0 1zm-6.5-3h1v1h1v1h-1v1h-1v-1h-1v-1h1v-1z"/>
                                    <path d="M3.051 3.26a.5.5 0 0 1 .354-.613l1.932-.518a.5.5 0 0 1 .62.39c.655-.079 1.35-.117 2.043-.117.72 0 1.443.041 2.12.126a.5.5 0 0 1 .622-.399l1.932.518a.5.5 0 0 1 .306.729c.14.09.266.19.373.297.408.408.78 1.05 1.095 1.772.32.733.599 1.591.805 2.466.206.875.34 1.78.364 2.606.024.816-.059 1.602-.328 2.21a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445.83c-.636-.067-1.115-.394-1.513-.773-.245-.232-.496-.526-.739-.808-.126-.148-.25-.292-.368-.423-.728-.804-1.597-1.527-3.224-1.527-1.627 0-2.496.723-3.224 1.527-.119.131-.242.275-.368.423-.243.282-.494.575-.739.808-.398.38-.877.706-1.513.773a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445-.83c-.27-.608-.352-1.395-.329-2.21.024-.826.16-1.73.365-2.606.206-.875.486-1.733.805-2.466.315-.722.687-1.364 1.094-1.772a2.34 2.34 0 0 1 .433-.335.504.504 0 0 1-.028-.079zm2.036.412c-.877.185-1.469.443-1.733.708-.276.276-.587.783-.885 1.465a13.748 13.748 0 0 0-.748 2.295 12.351 12.351 0 0 0-.339 2.406c-.022.755.062 1.368.243 1.776a.42.42 0 0 0 .426.24c.327-.034.61-.199.929-.502.212-.202.4-.423.615-.674.133-.156.276-.323.44-.504C4.861 9.969 5.978 9.027 8 9.027s3.139.942 3.965 1.855c.164.181.307.348.44.504.214.251.403.472.615.674.318.303.601.468.929.503a.42.42 0 0 0 .426-.241c.18-.408.265-1.02.243-1.776a12.354 12.354 0 0 0-.339-2.406 13.753 13.753 0 0 0-.748-2.295c-.298-.682-.61-1.19-.885-1.465-.264-.265-.856-.523-1.733-.708-.85-.179-1.877-.27-2.913-.27-1.036 0-2.063.091-2.913.27z"/>
                                </svg></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "product-info">
                        <div class = "product-info-top">
                            <h2 class = "sm-title">Ratings</h2>
                            <div class = "rating">
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "far fa-star"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <a href = "#" class = "product-name">'.$chall["challName"].'</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a href = "#" class = "product-name">'.$chall["difficulty"].'</a>
                    </div>

                </div>';
                            }
                            
                        }
                    ?>
                    
                    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

In the first php block of code i am connecting to a mongodb i am using.
In this db, there are is a collection called **ctfsReverse** and **usersInfo** .
What i am doing is giving the value of each challenge name to the variable $btn :

```
foreach ($collectionCtfs as $chall){
    $btn = $chall["challName"];
```

Then i use this variable as an html attribute in the *value* and *name* fields :

```
<form action="rev.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="'.$btn.'" value="'.$btn.'" class = "btn-cart"> play later list
        <span><i class = "fas fa-plus"></i></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

So as you can see in the first block of my php code, i want to check for a post request, and if this post request was due to a button being pressed (where the buttons value is actually the $btn contents) i want to store in my db the name of the button that was pressed :

```
$query = $db->usersInfo;
$filter = array('_id'=>$_SESSION['user']);
$update = array('$addToSet'=>array('ctfs'=>$btn));
$query->updateOne($filter,$update);
```

But the $btn variable seems to not be visible to the first php block of code. When i press the button, the $btn value does not get stored in the database.

How can i make the $btn globally defined?
I tried using php $GLOBALS but it didnt work.
I even tried checking for button being pressed in the second php block of code, but this didnt work either :

```html
<div class = "container">
                <h1 class = "lg-title">Welcome to the Reverse Engineering challenges</h1>
                
                <div class = "product-items">
                
                    <?php
                        $db = $m->users;
                        $collection = $db->usersInfo;
                        
                        $collectionAdmin = $db->adminInfo;
                        $query = $db->adminInfo->findOne(array('email'=>'adminMail@protonmail.com'));
                        if($query["timesLogged"] == "0"){
                            $db = $m->ctfs;
                            $collectionCtfs = $db->ctfsReverse->find();
                            foreach ($collectionCtfs as $chall){
                                $btn = $chall["challName"];
                                #echo $btn;
                                echo '<div class = "product">
                    <div class = "product-content">
                        <div class = "product-img">
                            <img src = "images/rev.png" alt = "product image">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "product-btns">
                            <form action="rev.php" method="post">
                                <button type="submit" name="'.$btn.'" value="'.$btn.'" class = "btn-cart"> play later list
                                    <span><i class = "fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                            <button type = "button" class = "btn-buy"> Play now
                                <span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-controller" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M11.5 6.027a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1 .5.5 0 0 0 0 1zm2.5-.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1 .5.5 0 0 0 0 1zm-6.5-3h1v1h1v1h-1v1h-1v-1h-1v-1h1v-1z"/>
                                    <path d="M3.051 3.26a.5.5 0 0 1 .354-.613l1.932-.518a.5.5 0 0 1 .62.39c.655-.079 1.35-.117 2.043-.117.72 0 1.443.041 2.12.126a.5.5 0 0 1 .622-.399l1.932.518a.5.5 0 0 1 .306.729c.14.09.266.19.373.297.408.408.78 1.05 1.095 1.772.32.733.599 1.591.805 2.466.206.875.34 1.78.364 2.606.024.816-.059 1.602-.328 2.21a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445.83c-.636-.067-1.115-.394-1.513-.773-.245-.232-.496-.526-.739-.808-.126-.148-.25-.292-.368-.423-.728-.804-1.597-1.527-3.224-1.527-1.627 0-2.496.723-3.224 1.527-.119.131-.242.275-.368.423-.243.282-.494.575-.739.808-.398.38-.877.706-1.513.773a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445-.83c-.27-.608-.352-1.395-.329-2.21.024-.826.16-1.73.365-2.606.206-.875.486-1.733.805-2.466.315-.722.687-1.364 1.094-1.772a2.34 2.34 0 0 1 .433-.335.504.504 0 0 1-.028-.079zm2.036.412c-.877.185-1.469.443-1.733.708-.276.276-.587.783-.885 1.465a13.748 13.748 0 0 0-.748 2.295 12.351 12.351 0 0 0-.339 2.406c-.022.755.062 1.368.243 1.776a.42.42 0 0 0 .426.24c.327-.034.61-.199.929-.502.212-.202.4-.423.615-.674.133-.156.276-.323.44-.504C4.861 9.969 5.978 9.027 8 9.027s3.139.942 3.965 1.855c.164.181.307.348.44.504.214.251.403.472.615.674.318.303.601.468.929.503a.42.42 0 0 0 .426-.241c.18-.408.265-1.02.243-1.776a12.354 12.354 0 0 0-.339-2.406 13.753 13.753 0 0 0-.748-2.295c-.298-.682-.61-1.19-.885-1.465-.264-.265-.856-.523-1.733-.708-.85-.179-1.877-.27-2.913-.27-1.036 0-2.063.091-2.913.27z"/>
                                </svg></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "product-info">
                        <div class = "product-info-top">
                            <h2 class = "sm-title">Ratings</h2>
                            <div class = "rating">
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "far fa-star"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <a href = "#" class = "product-name">'.$chall["challName"].'</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a href = "#" class = "product-name">'.$chall["difficulty"].'</a>
                    </div>

                </div>';
                            }
                            
                        }
              if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        if(isset($_POST[$btn])){
            echo $btn;
            echo "</script>alert($btn)</script>";
            $query = $db->usersInfo;
            $filter = array('_id'=>$_SESSION['user']);
            $update = array('$addToSet'=>array('ctfs'=>$btn));
            $query->updateOne($filter,$update);
        }
    }
                    ?>
                    
                    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Edit : Also, if i try to "View page source", the *name* and *value* attributes get the correct values :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Cyberdemia</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <!-- font awesome -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dbed6b6114.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>



        
        <div class="toggle"></div>

        <div class = "products">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <!--Will edit these in the future to get styles such as on-hover etc.-->
                    <li><a href="../ctfs.php"><small>Back</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="../../home/website.php"><small>Home</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="../../userProfile/userProfile.php"><small>Profile</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="../../signOut/signout.php"><small>Sign out</small></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class = "container">
                <h1 class = "lg-title">Welcome to the Reverse Engineering challenges</h1>
                
                <div class = "product-items">
                
                    <div class = "product">
                    <div class = "product-content">
                        <div class = "product-img">
                            <img src = "images/rev.png" alt = "product image">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "product-btns">
                            <form action="rev.php" method="post">
                                <button type="submit" name="rev level 1" value="rev level 1" class = "btn-cart"> play later list
                                    <span><i class = "fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                            <button type = "button" class = "btn-buy"> Play now
                                <span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-controller" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M11.5 6.027a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1 .5.5 0 0 0 0 1zm2.5-.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1 .5.5 0 0 0 0 1zm-6.5-3h1v1h1v1h-1v1h-1v-1h-1v-1h1v-1z"/>
                                    <path d="M3.051 3.26a.5.5 0 0 1 .354-.613l1.932-.518a.5.5 0 0 1 .62.39c.655-.079 1.35-.117 2.043-.117.72 0 1.443.041 2.12.126a.5.5 0 0 1 .622-.399l1.932.518a.5.5 0 0 1 .306.729c.14.09.266.19.373.297.408.408.78 1.05 1.095 1.772.32.733.599 1.591.805 2.466.206.875.34 1.78.364 2.606.024.816-.059 1.602-.328 2.21a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445.83c-.636-.067-1.115-.394-1.513-.773-.245-.232-.496-.526-.739-.808-.126-.148-.25-.292-.368-.423-.728-.804-1.597-1.527-3.224-1.527-1.627 0-2.496.723-3.224 1.527-.119.131-.242.275-.368.423-.243.282-.494.575-.739.808-.398.38-.877.706-1.513.773a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445-.83c-.27-.608-.352-1.395-.329-2.21.024-.826.16-1.73.365-2.606.206-.875.486-1.733.805-2.466.315-.722.687-1.364 1.094-1.772a2.34 2.34 0 0 1 .433-.335.504.504 0 0 1-.028-.079zm2.036.412c-.877.185-1.469.443-1.733.708-.276.276-.587.783-.885 1.465a13.748 13.748 0 0 0-.748 2.295 12.351 12.351 0 0 0-.339 2.406c-.022.755.062 1.368.243 1.776a.42.42 0 0 0 .426.24c.327-.034.61-.199.929-.502.212-.202.4-.423.615-.674.133-.156.276-.323.44-.504C4.861 9.969 5.978 9.027 8 9.027s3.139.942 3.965 1.855c.164.181.307.348.44.504.214.251.403.472.615.674.318.303.601.468.929.503a.42.42 0 0 0 .426-.241c.18-.408.265-1.02.243-1.776a12.354 12.354 0 0 0-.339-2.406 13.753 13.753 0 0 0-.748-2.295c-.298-.682-.61-1.19-.885-1.465-.264-.265-.856-.523-1.733-.708-.85-.179-1.877-.27-2.913-.27-1.036 0-2.063.091-2.913.27z"/>
                                </svg></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "product-info">
                        <div class = "product-info-top">
                            <h2 class = "sm-title">Ratings</h2>
                            <div class = "rating">
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "far fa-star"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <a href = "#" class = "product-name">rev level 1</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a href = "#" class = "product-name">difficulty - easy</a>
                    </div>

                </div><div class = "product">
                    <div class = "product-content">
                        <div class = "product-img">
                            <img src = "images/rev.png" alt = "product image">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "product-btns">
                            <form action="rev.php" method="post">
                                <button type="submit" name="rev level 2" value="rev level 2" class = "btn-cart"> play later list
                                    <span><i class = "fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                            <button type = "button" class = "btn-buy"> Play now
                                <span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-controller" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M11.5 6.027a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1 .5.5 0 0 0 0 1zm2.5-.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 1 0 0-1 .5.5 0 0 0 0 1zm-6.5-3h1v1h1v1h-1v1h-1v-1h-1v-1h1v-1z"/>
                                    <path d="M3.051 3.26a.5.5 0 0 1 .354-.613l1.932-.518a.5.5 0 0 1 .62.39c.655-.079 1.35-.117 2.043-.117.72 0 1.443.041 2.12.126a.5.5 0 0 1 .622-.399l1.932.518a.5.5 0 0 1 .306.729c.14.09.266.19.373.297.408.408.78 1.05 1.095 1.772.32.733.599 1.591.805 2.466.206.875.34 1.78.364 2.606.024.816-.059 1.602-.328 2.21a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445.83c-.636-.067-1.115-.394-1.513-.773-.245-.232-.496-.526-.739-.808-.126-.148-.25-.292-.368-.423-.728-.804-1.597-1.527-3.224-1.527-1.627 0-2.496.723-3.224 1.527-.119.131-.242.275-.368.423-.243.282-.494.575-.739.808-.398.38-.877.706-1.513.773a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445-.83c-.27-.608-.352-1.395-.329-2.21.024-.826.16-1.73.365-2.606.206-.875.486-1.733.805-2.466.315-.722.687-1.364 1.094-1.772a2.34 2.34 0 0 1 .433-.335.504.504 0 0 1-.028-.079zm2.036.412c-.877.185-1.469.443-1.733.708-.276.276-.587.783-.885 1.465a13.748 13.748 0 0 0-.748 2.295 12.351 12.351 0 0 0-.339 2.406c-.022.755.062 1.368.243 1.776a.42.42 0 0 0 .426.24c.327-.034.61-.199.929-.502.212-.202.4-.423.615-.674.133-.156.276-.323.44-.504C4.861 9.969 5.978 9.027 8 9.027s3.139.942 3.965 1.855c.164.181.307.348.44.504.214.251.403.472.615.674.318.303.601.468.929.503a.42.42 0 0 0 .426-.241c.18-.408.265-1.02.243-1.776a12.354 12.354 0 0 0-.339-2.406 13.753 13.753 0 0 0-.748-2.295c-.298-.682-.61-1.19-.885-1.465-.264-.265-.856-.523-1.733-.708-.85-.179-1.877-.27-2.913-.27-1.036 0-2.063.091-2.913.27z"/>
                                </svg></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "product-info">
                        <div class = "product-info-top">
                            <h2 class = "sm-title">Ratings</h2>
                            <div class = "rating">
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "fas fa-star"></i></span>
                                <span><i class = "far fa-star"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <a href = "#" class = "product-name">rev level 2</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a href = "#" class = "product-name">difficulty - medium</a>
                    </div>

                </div>                    
                    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you're missing an assignment of `$btn = $_POST['btn'];` as you are saving the `$btn` value to the db but nowhere are you setting that to what was POST'ed.

Comment: But $btn is already given the value of $_POST['btn']. Also, even if that was the case, these should be an empty string stored in db. Instead, nothing gets stored. Also, if i try to print the $btn after the POST request detection, it does not get printed, meaning the code doesnt make it inside the if statement.

Either way, i tried what you said but again, no luck.

Comment: Apologies I mis-read, you have `$_POST[$btn]` not `$_POST['btn']`. Can you set the form field name to just `btn` or does the name of the field need to be the value? * referencing this `<button type="submit" name="'.$btn.'" value="'.$btn.'" class = "btn-cart">`

Comment: So have you made sure that `if(isset($_POST[$btn])){` gets triggered? By echoing something else than an empty string inside? `$btn = '';`, so`echo $btn` wouldn't show up anywhere. `echo "</script>alert($btn)</script>";` Two _closing_ script tags?? Take a look at the source code of that button, what is its name?

Comment: @ cOle2 : Yes, i want the name of the field to have the value of $btn. For example, if $btn = "cOle2" i would like the button to be <button type="submit" name="cOle2" value="cOle2" class = "btn-cart">

@brombeer : No, if(isset($_POST[$btn])){ is not always getting triggered. I just realised that if the "name" attributes value has spaces, the if(isset($_POST[$btn])){ wont get triggered. But if the "name" attributes value has no spaces inside, it will get triggered. Just not by using $btn.

Comment: @brombeer 
For example, if in the first php block of code i have : if(isset($_POST["test"])){ , and the second block of php is as in my post, (say $btn="test"), html name attribute gets the value of "test" correctly, and the if(isset($_POST["test"])){  gets triggered.
But if i solely use $btn in the if(isset , it wont get triggered.
Also you are right, mistyped two closing script tags, but still the alert was printed when i used "test" in the if(isset

Comment: This is confusing. Why does the button's name have to be variable? Why not just `name` the button something like "button" and only change its value? What is the use of having the button's name the same as the value? That's not needed imho. You get the value from the button's `value` attribute

Comment: @brombeer i dont want the name of the button to be variable. I want the name of the button to get the value stored in this variable. 
Say i want name to be **name="button"**. I want to be able to pass "button" with the help of a php variable.

The idea of what i am trying to achieve is to dynamically load entries from the database and get the value of each key named "challName" (as you can see at *$btn = $chall["challName"];* ) and use that value as the buttons name.

Comment: @brombeer 
So by doing this, whenever I insert new entries in the db, the page will load and display them dynamically by getting the "challName" as the name of the button and echoing the html code i posted. 
You get the idea? I cant know what new entries will be and what name shall be in the button of the "new"/"extra" html code that will be echoed.
So by loading and storing the "challName" of new db entries, I'd like to use them in the buttons name and then check in the post request if this "new" button's name was pressed.

I hope it is more clear now:)

Comment: I still think this overcomplicates things (as you can see ;)). As I already mentioned, why not get the `value` of that button to determine which one was pressed? Let's assume you have two forms, each with one button: `<button name="button" value="rev level 1">` and `<button name="button" value="rev level 2">`. Press the first one, `$_POST['button']` will be `rev level 1`. Press the second one, `$_POST['button']` will be `rev level 2`. That's how you determine which one was pressed. You can now load your db entries based on `$_POST['button']`.

Comment: @brombeer You are absolutely right. I finally got what you meant. It was not clear to me how these *name* and *value* attributes got handled by html. But now it is clear.
Thank you very much:)